# How to list the all the trace events enabled in the oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration, plsqldeveloper

please suggest the sql query to list the all active trace events in the oracle database. More ora trace log files are getting generated for the particular database . This  might be the cause of trace was enabled for some objects or sessions or sql and missed to disable it.

Thanks,
Sasikumar.

Comment: Is this related to E Biz Suite ?

Comment: No.. it's normal oracle 11g database..

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

SQL> oradebug eventdump session